# Convert a CSV file to XML

Tags: xml, shell, csv, unix

I'm trying to convert a CSV file to XML using Unix shell. I believe this code will do it, but something is wrong with it. Can anyone help me?

```
!/bin/ksh
BEGIN {OFS = "\n"}
NR == 1 {for (i = 1; i <=NF; i++)
            tag[i]=$i
         print "<" node "XML>"}
```

This section is for the field names

```
NR != 1 {print "   <" node ">"
         for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            print "      <" tag[i] ">" $i "</" tag[i] ">"
         print "   </" node ">"}
END {print "</" node "XML>"}
```

Comment: You should explain what you expect your code to do exactly and what happens instead. Currently, somebody who wants to answer your question would have to guess the intention of your non-working snippet and then fix it.

Comment: I just formatted your code blocks, but didn't fix obvious issues like incorrect shebang line (should start with `#!`) and the fact that you (and the shebang line) say "shell script" but use awk.